# How to change Windows Explorer's show columns context menu

Tags: windows-explorer, context-menu

Is there any way to change this menu's list of columns for any and all folders, in such way that whenever I want to add an actually useful column to the current view I don't need to look it up in the "More..." list?

[image: Explorer's short column list]